# how to retrieve data using uuid in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

halo guys i wan to retrieve a particular object using `DRF RETRIEVEAPIVIEW` using `UUID` as my pk but i'm getting

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

error below is my APIVIEW and url

```
class RetrieveProfile(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
```

```
    path('<uuid:id>/display',RetrieveProfile.as_view(), name="display-profile"),
```

any help on how to solve this ?

Comment: The id that you are using to get the user, did you check if that exists in the UserProfile ?